# Make :after element expand to full width if parent overflows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I use something similar to this for my menu - the red line in reality has an image background and should underline the whole content or go to the full width.

It works fine on large screen, but on small (here simulated by setting width), the red line ends before the actual content.

Any way to make it expand to the full width?

(I can use javascript (even jquery), but I'd prefer not to)

```css
.outer {
  font-size: 16pt;
}

.menu {
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
    position:relative;
}

.menu:after {
    content:'';
    background-color:red;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
    <div class="menu"> 
        This is on desktop and everything is fine.
    </div>
</div>

<div class="outer" style="width: 200px">
    <div class="menu"> 
        This is on phone, the content overflows as you can see.
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a media query to target mobile only and reset your CSS (replace the 200px with your mobile screen resolution, typically 480px):

```
@media screen and (max-width: 200px) {

  .menu {
      overflow-x: initial;
      white-space: normal;
  }

}
```

Comment: so it's the whitespace causing this?

Comment: Yes. Your background will stretch 100% but as your copy won't break, it will stretch and overflow. Another workaround would be setting your background position as fixed, this way you can scroll to see the text but the bg stays in a fixed position (although I wouldn't recommend this for mobile devices).

Answer (score -1):

i may have a simple solution for you problem : set a border and delet the after element.

```
.menu {
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
    position:relative;
    border-bottom:2px solid red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ex0p6thd/

Comment: I said it has an image background, I'm not that stupid, I know how to make a border.

Comment: You don't need to be rude. I hope for you someone else help you. I'am done here.